# Nodejs micro service timed out while hitting to other micro service

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am hosting microservices on ec2 instance.
Everything is working fine when we run it on dev environment. But when I run it on https (prod) environment. One of the service is not able to hit another service getting the below error :

```
0|auth_mgr | error: Error Authenticating User:  Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.7.165.49:3001
0|auth_mgr |     at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
0|auth_mgr |     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
0|auth_mgr |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1195:14)
```

When I hit from postman from local machine it works :

```
var userURL   = configuration.url.user + '/pool/' + userName;
    request({
        url: userURL,
        method: "GET",
        json: true,
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            callback(null, body);
        }
    else {
        if (!error) {
            var lookupError = new Error("Failed looking up user pool: " + response.body.Error);
            callback(lookupError, response);
        }
        else {
            callback(error, response)
        }
    }
});
```

url eg. https://abc.xyz.com:3001/user/pool/john@doe.com

Comment: Are you able to hit the ec2 API from Postman and does it return the same error as above? I assume that error you've shown is from the terminal

Comment: @Stretch0 Yes I am able to hit it from my local machine through Postman and it is working fine. It is not giving me the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have added security group to open the port for "anywhere". This thing worked for me.